# I got an error "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

Tags: laravel

I'm using DB Facade for fetching user id which gives perfect output.
But, when I use that result for Eloquent it gives me an error which says,

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

My Controller Code :

```
public function complete_progress(){
    $task_id = session('task_id');
    $e_user = DB::table('e_users')
             ->join('tasks', function($join) use ($task_id){
               $join->on('e_users.id', '=','tasks.task_assign_to')
               ->where('tasks.id', '=', $task_id);
             })
             ->first();
    $data = e_user::find($e_user);
    $task = task::find($task_id);
    $task->task_status = "Completed";
    $data->pending -= 1;
    $data->completed += 1;
    $task->save();
    $data->save();
    session()->flash('complete', 'Task Completed');
    return redirect('homepage');
}
```

Comment: what do u mean when I use that result? Where is the error being thrown ?

Comment: When i use that $e_user variable in e_user::find($e_user). And when I dd($data) I got that error.

Comment: e_user is a model? try this: $data = e_user::find($e_user->id);

Comment: Why you are getting data again ($data = e_user::find($e_user);) when you already has $e_user?

Comment: Don't use the DB facade if you have a model. You should be using eloquent relationships with `with` and `whereHas` to setup your conditions

Comment: Heyya... It works like a charm. Thanks man @LucasPiazzi  Please explain what that $e_user->id did??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the `id` on the find method:

```
$data = e_user::find(e_user->id);
```

When you use the `find()` method, laravel searchs for the object that matches with the id that you passed as a parameter, so you must pass a id on the parameter, not an entire object, as you did.

Comment: & why is it so?? Please explain

Comment: Here you re looking for the object that corresponds to the given id that you pass as a parameter. In your code you passed the entire object, thats why doesn't work. I edited my answer, take a look

Comment: Ahh... Thanks alot @LucasPiazzi

Comment: Glad i could help :)